# Why Nest.js throw a error when run main.js?

Tags: nestjs

I am using Nest.js to develop a web backend.

When I use `npm run build`, the cmd shows success.
[image]

But when I use `node dist/main.js`, the cmd shows error. But I'm sure this file exist and in develop mode `(npm run start)`, everything's ok.

[image]

This is github address.
https://github.com/Eve-1995/Oreo/tree/master/oreo-back-end

What should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`entities: [__dirname + '/../**/**/!(*.d).entity.{ts,js}'],` is doing the trick for me both in production and dev envs.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is in TypeOrm config.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    ClassificationModule,
    ArticleModule,
    UserModule,
    CommentModule,
    FragmentModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      // logging: ["query"],
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: '123456',
      database: 'myblog',
      entities: ['src/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}'], // <-- replace it to 'dist/**/**.entity.js' in prod mode or use relative path
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: It's not this file. This file is correct. But in some files I import entities not in the way of  `relative`, so the path has string `src/`. Anyway, thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to add this in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"paths": {
    "src/*": ["./src/*"]
}
```

TS can now correctly transform the `src/` alias import when building the project.