# npm run start:dev cannot find module

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

npm run start works fine, but npm run start: dev throws this error:

```
7:14:22 PM - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'src/models/note.model'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anuitex-169\Desktop\VersF\nest\server\dist\note\note.service.js:17:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

This error appeared from the very beginning of my project, and I can’t understand why. I decided to forget about this problem since npm run start works well. But somehow uncomfortable (

[My app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL662.png)
My package.json file:

```
    {
      "name": "server",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "description": "",
      "author": "",
      "license": "MIT",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "rimraf dist && tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
        "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\"",
        "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
        "start:dev": "tsc-watch -p tsconfig.build.json --onSuccess \"node dist/main.js\"",
        "start:debug": "tsc-watch -p tsconfig.build.json --onSuccess \"node --inspect-brk dist/main.js\"",
        "start:prod": "node dist/main.js",
        "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
        "test": "jest",
        "test:watch": "jest --watch",
        "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
        "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
        "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@nestjs/common": "^6.0.0",
        "@nestjs/core": "^6.0.0",
        "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.0.0",
        "@nestjs/typeorm": "^6.1.3",
        "mongodb": "^3.3.2",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
        "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
        "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
        "typeorm": "^0.2.19"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@nestjs/testing": "^6.0.0",
        "@types/express": "4.16.1",
        "@types/jest": "24.0.11",
        "@types/multer": "^1.3.10",
        "@types/node": "11.13.4",
        "@types/supertest": "2.0.7",
        "jest": "24.7.1",
        "prettier": "1.17.0",
        "supertest": "4.0.2",
        "ts-jest": "24.0.2",
        "ts-node": "8.1.0",
        "tsc-watch": "2.2.1",
        "tsconfig-paths": "3.8.0",
        "tslint": "5.16.0",
        "typescript": "3.4.3"
      },
      "jest": {
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
          "js",
          "json",
          "ts"
        ],
        "rootDir": ".",
        "roots": [
          "<rootDir>/src/",
          "<rootDir>/libs/",
          "<rootDir>/apps/"
        ],
        "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
        "transform": {
          "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
        },
        "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
        "testEnvironment": "node"
      }
    }
```

Please help me deal with this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your AppModule looks fine, so I have to wonder if something is happening in your NoteService, which this line makes it looks like that is the case `at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anuitex-169\Desktop\VersF\nest\server\dist\note\note.service.js:17:22)`.

If I had to bet, you are trying to read the module from your `src` directory while you are in your `dist` directory (at least by standard Typescript compilation). Instead of using an import like `src/models/note.model` you should use an import that takes into account the path from the current file (such as `../models/note.model`). You may need to change that a bit more, but that's the idea of what should happen

Comment: Jay is very close I believe. Most likely very similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57964735/4319037 (both are about dist/dev and correctly locating entities; please note a bit different regexp). 
Does your `build` run correctly?

Comment: The glob actually looks correct in this case, using dirname instead of a hardcoded src or dist, in just trying to follow the stack trace that says the note.service.js is trying to import from src/models/note.model